# Is it possible to run selenium tests through Jenkins without using Testng framework

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

We didn't use testNg framework in our selenium Automation framework, so
I would like to know the possibility of running selenium tests through Jenkins, without having testNg framework.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins allows you to run arbitrary scripts/programs, so nothing really prevents you from running selenium tests without testNg. For example we use the [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) to spin up our application and selenium container to run tests.

Answer (score 0):

First, selenium does not depend on TestNG as it is api which accessible using simple plain java (assuming you use java). You could write void main then run the selenium using void main, it would be okay

Second, jenkins has many ways of running build scripts/ test script, for example you could use execute shell / windows batch command which is basically representation of linux shell/ windows DOS, or you could use container like docker plugin, etc.

The usage of test framework usually to help you manage your tests well, such as parallel test, data driven test, and help in collecting test result, and could be consumed easily by CI tools like jenkins such as using junit report plugin, xunit report plugin

So if you want to try running selenium using jenkins, you could create void main , then run the test using shell/windows command and call that file that contains main

Hope this helps